# Incorrect Image path inline style background-image html

Tags: html, css

I do dynamic background-image So I get variable from back-end, the image path seem correct[image] but i checked console it displayed error with resouse and it display incorrect url seem as below:[image]
I use aspnet core for backend, thank you

Comment: Why does it start with _localhost_ if it's a resource from the backend?

Comment: i ran one more project on my local machine as backend server

Comment: You can test it with your browser since it's a GET request. And if that doesn't work, the image is likely not correctly configured in the backend

Comment: Try changing the `original\flowers` with forward slash in the url.

Comment: `400` server response means `Bad Request` (see [MDN doc for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400), which indicates a client error like a malformed URL syntax, etc. As @ServeshChaturvedi noted, the backslash character `\ ` inside your file name might be the culprit. If it is indeed part of the file name itself, you might want to change it to another character like a dash `-`. If it is a typo for a directory name, you might need to replace it with a forward slash `/`.